# how to test and debug all android device

Tags: android, debugging, testing, device

A week ago,I developed a app and published to google play.
[App Link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tiny.fakeapp)

This app use camera and activity-alias . It works fine in my phones(S1,S2,New One,Sony Xperia v). But after i published to google play , i found many problems,like HTC one x camera  or HTC butterfly activity-alias not working in my app . I dont have these phones ,so its hard to debug .

Is there a good way to solve this situation ? I used some test websites like appThwack   and Keynote. But it only response me error message, I am hard to debug too,because it need to upload apk to test(spend long time).

Answer (score 0):

I have found that with Android getting feedback from users on their specific device in inevitable, and unless you have those devices to test on beforehand you won't know until someone tells you.

Android is on so many devices with so many different screen sizes and hardware manufacturers it can be very difficult to get it working correctly 100% across the board. Knowing what devices have the issue helps point in the right direction, but nothing beats testing on the actual device.

Comment: Thank your reply. So if I found a type device has a bug , I can only find the same device to debug? lol....

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Android Studio. You can preview your app for all screen resolution in one shot. For specific screen relotions and density, create an AVD. I think for independent developers, this is the best way (Considering your app runs on Emulator :-))

Comment: Thank your reply. I know screen resolution problems can use those ways to solve . Now that bothers me is my app responses different result on different devices. It has bugs in some devices.

Comment: There are online sites where you can pay and get devices for testing. They almost have all devices with them. It wasn't that expensive also. You get to test on actual physical devices online. I did that and was really helpful. Though its bit cumbersome but I felt it was the only option :)